# How do I activate the built-in flash on the Canon Powershot G5 X?

Tags: flash, popup-flash, powershot

I have a problem with the onboard flash of my camera.

I can't figure out how to activate the flash...

Even in automatic mode, the camera is not flashing in dark scenes. I turned off the light in the room and it was really dark. But no flash...

The flash has to be opened manually, but how can I activate it? There is a button with a flash symbol, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to use flash without manually opening it first? I don't know about G5x but G16 will only attempt to use flash if you have opened it manually first -  unlike in some dslrs which will pop up the flash when needed.

Comment: When you see "in automatic mode" do you mean the camera shooting mode? Or the flash mode setting in the camera menus?

Comment: Automatic shooting mode. The flash is disables and I can't activate it. The menu no. 5 for flash configuration only shows a configuration for the red eye reduction. And the flash button doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah i got it...
There was a plastic cover on the flash mount that was some kind of blocking the onboard flash.
Removing the plastic cover unlocks all flash features.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't figure out how to activate the flash...

[Page 91 of your PowerShot G5 X manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/3/0300020273/01/psg5x-cu-en.pdf#page=91) explains that you activate the flash by lifting it up. Other cameras have a button or switch that you can use to release the flash, but on this model you just grasp the flash on the sides and swing it up into position. Once you've done that, you can access the flash settings screen with the ▶︎ button.

Comment: Yeah i am opening the flash by hand and trying to manage it through the flash Button (▶︎), but pressing the button doesn't do anything and the flash isn't flashing.